# Why is this angularjs on jsFiddle not working

Tags: angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/maxl/tNZAm/102/

I would expect to have the repeater listing this array :

> function MyControl(){
>       var self = this;
>
> ```
> self.values = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
> self.selectedIndex = -1;
>
> self.toggleSelect = function(ind){
>     if( ind === self.selectedIndex ){
>         self.selectedIndex = -1;
>     } else{
>         self.selectedIndex = ind;
>     }
> }
>
> self.getClass = function(ind){
>     if( ind === self.selectedIndex ){
>         return "selected";
>     } else{
>         return "";
>     }
> }
>
> self.getButtonLabel = function(ind){
>     if( ind === self.selectedIndex ){
>         return "Deselect";
>     } else{
>         return "Select";
>     }
> } }​
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `$scope` injectable to attach data to the DOM. Additionally, you were loading Angular.js twice (once via the "Choose Framework" dropdown and once via the "Add Resources" panel), resulting in a very, very strange bug.

Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/tNZAm/103/

```
function MyControl($scope){
    $scope.values = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
    $scope.selectedIndex = -1;

    $scope.toggleSelect = function(ind){
        if( ind === $scope.selectedIndex ){
            $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
        } else{
            $scope.selectedIndex = ind;
        }
    }

    $scope.getClass = function(ind){
        if( ind === $scope.selectedIndex ){
            return "selected";
        } else{
            return "";
        }
    }

    $scope.getButtonLabel = function(ind){
        if( ind === $scope.selectedIndex ){
            return "Deselect";
        } else{
            return "Select";
        }
    }
}​
```

Comment: Thanks, I copied this example from a jsFiddle that used an older version of angular, that tolerated the use of .this ....